# SSRS Formatting for negative numbers

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Ok, so I am familiar with formatting the colors of a cell like this

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Dollars.Value) < 0, "Red", "Black")
```

but, I have inherited a report that has 80 columns and 4 rows of calculated fields which all print out black. I have been tasked with changing the format to represent negative numbers as red.

Does anyone know of an easy was to represent "CurrentValue" in a formula instead of referencing the textbox or report field?

Something along the lines of

```
=IIF(SUM(CurrentCellValue) < 0, "Red", "Black")
```

This way I can select the whole table and add this formula to the font color. Otherwise I will have to change the formula on 80*4 fields. I really don't want to do that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the Color expression of the fields use the code below

`= Iif (Me.Value <0, "Red", "Black")`

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this can be set for multiple cells at once. Open the Properties window (F4), select all the cells that need the format, and put the expression into the `Color` property.

Comment: YES! That's it. Amazing. Took me 2 minutes to implement vs. hours and possible mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: About Niktrs solution it should be me.value instead of Me.Value

Comment: Nice but only worked for me when I removed the spaces before and after the Iif